# How to make extension both outlet (swift 2)

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-extensions

I created extension for UITextField. And I need the same extension for UITextView. How to make this extension available for all other views?

My extension code:

```
extension UITextField {

    func addTopBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, height: CGFloat) {
        let border = CALayer()
        border.backgroundColor = color.CGColor
        border.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, height)
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    }

    func addRightBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, height: CGFloat) {
        let border = CALayer()
        border.backgroundColor = color.CGColor
        border.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - height, 0, height, self.frame.size.height)
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    }

    func addBottomBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, height: CGFloat) {
        let border = CALayer()
        border.backgroundColor = color.CGColor
        border.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - height, self.frame.size.width, height)
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    }

    func addLeftBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, height: CGFloat) {
        let border = CALayer()
        border.backgroundColor = color.CGColor
        border.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, height, self.frame.size.height)
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just making extension to `UIView`? As the other classes (`UITextField`, `UITextView`, `UILabel`, ...) extend `UIView`, they all should have it.

Comment: @mad_manny, you are right. it worked perfect. thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only create the extension for `UIView`.
As the other classes (`UITextField`, `UITextView`, `UILabel`, ...) extend `UIView`, they all should have your functions available.

**NOTE**: This requires that the functions work for UIView and don't contain specific operations (e.g. accessing properties only available in `UITextView`).

Answer (score 1):

In the case when you want an extension for only a few classes, you could define a protocol and provide default implementations in the protocol, then extend the classes with the new protocol.  Here's a trivial example you can run in playground:

```
protocol foo {
    func bar() -> String;
}

extension foo {
    func bar() -> String {
        return "bar"
    }
}

extension Float: foo {}
extension Int: foo {}


let i = 12
print(i.bar())

let f:Float = 1.0
print (f.bar())
```